# unknown property LeadStandardController.Savedoc

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce-id

I am encountering the error:

> Unknown property LeadStandardController.Savedoc

How do I fix it? Code below.

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="attachmentsample">               
    <apex:form >
        <apex:sectionHeader title="Upload attachment document."/>
            <apex:pageblock >
                <apex:pageblocksection columns="1">
                    <apex:inputfile value="{!myfile.body}" filename="{!myfile.Name}" />    
                </apex:pageblocksection>
            </apex:pageblock>   
    </apex:form> 
    <input type="submit" action="{!Savedoc}" name="submit"/>
</apex:page>
```

**Extension**

```
public class attachmentsample {
        public attachmentsample(Lead controller) {
        }
        public attachmentsample(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        }
        Public Attachment myfile;
        Public Attachment getmyfile()
        {
            myfile = new Attachment();
            return myfile;
        }  
        Public Pagereference Savedoc()
        {
            String accid = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('id');
            Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = accid, name=myfile.name, body = myfile.body);        
             /* insert the attachment */
             insert a;
            return NULL;
        }   

    }  
}
```

Comment: your input tag should be a commandButton

Answer (score 1):

Your markup should not even compile. The `apex:input` tag has no attribute called `action`. The error message is a little opaque, but that's the source of the problem. Here are some components that do have an `action` attribute that can call an `Apex` method:

- `apex:commandButton` ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm))
- `apex:commandLink` ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandLink.htm))
- `apex:actionFunction` ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm))
- `apex:actionSupport` ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm))

If you are trying to create a submit button, `commandButton` is the way to go.